# how do i store the current browser URL as a variable that I can use in a different test in cypress

Tags: cypress

I am trying to read the current URL of my browser, store it in a variable and use it in another test as cy.visit()
I tried using cypress env variable like storing the current url and call it in another test but it failed to get to the right URL.

I tried to store the current browser URL as
**Cypress.env('urlValue', cy.url())**

and call it in another test like

**cy.visit(Cypress.env('urlValue'))**

but it doesn't seems to be going to the right URL.

Answer (score 0):

`cy.url()` is an asynchronous command, and won't yield a value (or at least not a string value) if added to `Cypress.env()`. Instead, you should take the yielded value of `cy.url()` and use that.

```js
cy.url().then((url) => {
  Cypress.env('urlValue', url);
});
```